# Does FCP X make room for sound editors?

Tags: picture

I'm not too familiar with the program but I have read that…"“You can’t assign audio tracks.” (What he means is audio on the timeline is freeform, and can’t be set to be on a track designated “A1″ or “A2″.)  The new Automatic Duck can output these tracks in a particular order, I am informed, but it’s not clear exactly how the editor controls this."

Maybe this means that the more uneducated directors will not be able to just give the "post-production" to "an editor?"

Answer (score 3):

I'm hearing a whole load of issues with the newest version of Final Cut Pro from various colleagues, mostly that it's lost so much functionality that it is more of a pro version of iMovie than an update to Final Cut Pro. I would stay away from it for now if you possibly can.

Answer (score 0):

Final Cut Pro X is an abomination. The biggest problem is that it doesn't do OMF or AAF exports.

It's an absolute nightmare, and serious professional editors (and indie filmmakers) are going to be leaving the FCP ship in droves. It's sad, because Apple took a capable market leading product and just killed it and left it to die in the street.

Read up on the workflows for Avid Media Composer and Adobe Premiere Pro, that's where the market is headed now.

Comment: That being said, I have this quote about apple.  " Apple has followed the typical Apple sequence: (1) throw out something that’s popular and comfortable but increasingly ancient, (2) replace it with something that’s slick and modern and forward-looking and incomplete, (3) spend another year finishing it up, restoring missing pieces.
"

Answer (score 0):

Final Cut Pro has never been able to export OMFs or AAFs.  You can do it with third-party plugins.  I don't know if the market is headed somewhere else.  While major editing for episodics and television is still generally handled in AVID, many smaller editing houses are solely Final Cut, so I think there has been some misstatements.  Many advertising companies are solely on Final Cut as well.  Point is, I think Final Cut is still a capable program.

Comment: Well, Final Cut 7 is, sure. But those advertising companies are coming to the same conclusion that others are: that FCPX in its current as-released form doesn't have the features they need.

Comment: Are you sure FCP has never been able to export OMF/AAF? It's in the File menu, and been on every single FCP i've ever seen...

Comment: FCP 7 can absolutely export OMF's.  Agreed, there's far too much disinformation out there, but it's on both sides of this issue.

The fact of the matter is that this is an entirely new program, built from the ground up, more closely related to iMovie than FCP. Calling it FCP was more of a marketing decision because Apple view FCP more as a brand than a piece of software.  Understandable from Apple's point of view, but unfortunate.

I fear that Logic is going to be getting the Garageband treatment soon.

Answer (score 0):

I still wonder though will this make the industry not hand the "editing" over to the picture editor and instead hand the "editing" to the picture editor and a *gasp* sound editor.

Answer (score 0):

FCPX doesn't sound like it's good. But I'm always hesitant about upgrading too soon after new software is released; there are always bugs to iron out, right? I've heard lots of negative opinions of FCPX (including one from Hitler - search YouTube to see it) and nothing particularly positive. It doesn't concern me for the time being - I'll keep using FCP7.

I understand the main lure for editors is background rendering. I can see how that would be an attractive improvement.

Does anybody use Soundtrack Pro? I've always found it annoying. I'd much rather work in Logic and have better linkage with FCP. Maybe that's something waiting around the corner.

Comment: Im sure plenty of people use STP, but it frustrates me. the interface is seems really cluttered and i don't really like the way it handles aux's and automation.

Answer (score 0):

no omf export? thats embarassing.

Answer (score 0):

I purchased it and then asked for a refund (which I got). At the moment due to the OMF and other export options missing, FCPX is a close environment for everything apart from initial import and final export. So for the moment you won't be seeing any serious editor using it even though it has a great engine behind it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this question doesn't apply to established industry pro's or people in LA.  It partially stemmed from my experience in the Bay Area where people make films and then have picture editors crap on the audio track and call it done.